# MVC4 Internet Application Template to Kendo UI Conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, kendo-ui

- Im using Visual Studio'12 with MVC4 Internet Application Template.
- Im trying to convert the Template to use Kendo UI.
- I'm following the [Instructions](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#using-kendo-ui-in-asp.net-mvc-4-application) as where `Using Kendo UI in
  ASP.NET MVC 4 application` starts.

---

So far I have imported, changed code, calling code exactly the way i'm shown in the Tutorial.

- When I run my code I had lost my css - they use there own. I
  re-enabled mine by re-including

  ```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
  ```
- Now the Kendo controls show up with my CSS configurations.
- The Flaw is that the Kendo UI is not reacting to Mouse clicks like it
  is supposed to I'm really lost on this situation. Did anyone else run
  into this?

Kendo UI Support Team has so far not been able to help me out with this issue.

---

> Looking back through my code I am implementing...

```
        // The jQuery bundle
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));
```

Unsure if this would really call / load all scripts correctly i went back to using the origional that came with the Internet Application Template

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

*Please note that all other "Privious Code" from Internet Application Template was commented out and is not in use. (Besides content/css)*

---

- You should also note that currently my @(HTML.Kendo() helpers are
  showing

**"System.Web.Mvc.HTMLHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extentsion method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are  you missing a using directive or an assemnly reference?)"**

I have googled for this solution and for a short while the solution of adding `<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />` in the `web.config` of the Shared Folder was the solution.

now im Lost and Stuck any help is appreciated. - please let me know if you require additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer being that Something wasn't Removed, if you redo an Internet Application MVC4 Project ( I would assume also MVC3 ) remove the following lines at the bottom of the partial _Layout.cshtml file

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

For reasons <- I cannot explain, but sure is very logical, as in probably something being overwritten kept the Kendo from responding.

You will however want to keep 
        `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Hope this can help someone else!